# Build referer URL chains while crawling data through scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there any scrapy module available to build referrer chains while crawling urls.

Lets say for instance I start my crawl from http://www.example.com and move to http://www.new-example.com and then from http://www.new-example.com to http://very-new-example.com.

Can I create a url chains(a csv or json file) like this:

```
 http://www.example.com, http://www.new-example.com
 http://www.example.com, http://www.new-example.com, http://very-new-example.com
```

and so on, if there's no module or implementation available at the moment then what other options can I try?

Comment: There is no current implementation for that inside scrapy itself, you would have to call every url with a callback which supports `referer`. From what I see you could just use the `requests` library and execute your urls on a script with a `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can keep track of referrals by making a global list which accesible by all methods for example.

```
referral_url_list = []

def call_back1(self, response):
    self.referral_url_list.append(response.url)

def call_back1(self, response):
    self.referral_url_list.append(response.url)

def call_back1(self, response):
    self.referral_url_list.append(response.url)
```

after spider completion which is detected by spider [signals](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html). you can write [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or [json](https://gist.github.com/billroy/3761495) file in signal function